# How to get copy of my git repo into my react application and display all files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, git

can someone please guide to connect git repo to my react web application to view the files in that repo.

I am trying to implement a file explorer that will display the files in my git repository.

Please provide suggestion or any methods to do the same

Comment: This library exists for jquery, https://github.com/darcyclarke/Repo.js seems to be what you are looking for though if you want to avoid jquery you might need to recreate using react.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with `git`. You'd need to operate a web server that can access the storage device holding the files in your repository. This is just a static file server with the ability to also provide a directory listing. Is your repository data stored on GitHub?

Comment: yes, currently i have a repository in GitHub. I am trying to build a web app that can get a copy of my repo and display the files in my web page.